# Should we keep three different tags for Views, or should we merge all the tags, and use just one?

Tags: discussion, tags

Looking at the questions about [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views), I see there are 133 questions tagged [views](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/views), 39 questions tagged [views-2](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/views-2), and 35 questions tagged [views-3](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/views-3).
I doubt that all the questions tagged [views](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/views) are questions that don't depend from the Views version. The user interface of the module changed between Views 2 and Views 3; there are features that are only available on the latest version of Views that are not present in the previous version.

As most of the questions don't use a tag specific for the View version, considering that the View version can be reported in the question body, and considering that there are features in 7.x-3.x-dev that are not present in the official release 7.x-3 (the questions for both the versions would be tagged [views-3](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/views-3)), I suggest that we just use a single tag for Views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering that version tags are considered harmful, and that those tags have not been consistently and correctly used, I have made [views-2](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/views-2) [views-3](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/views-3) synonym of [views](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/views).

Answer (score 1):

I am of the opinion that the tags should remain separate. It may not make sense all the time but in a case like Views 2.x -> 3.x there are extensive architectural changes that can change the approach one would take to an answer.

I think that given what we know about Views and the fact that there are a significant percentage of Views questions that are tagged with an accurate, meaningful version number, I would be inclined to let those tags continue to exist organically.

Comment: 39 questions tagged "views-2" out a total of 207 means the 18.8%. Looking at some of the questions tagged "views," there are questions about how to do something with Views that don't report which version of Views it is being used; as the user interface changed in the 3.x branch (at least in the development snapshot), I think it's difficult to answer in a way that can help without to know the Views version.

Comment: With views-3 the Drupal version is important (sigh), as the UI changes didn't make it into D6